# Creating/Editing Existing Documents

Tags: google-drive

A document was shared with me, enabling me to edit it. However, whenever I open it, it only lets me view it, and anytime I try to open the "Open with Google Docs" tab, it acts as if I never pressed it, same as if I try to download it. Same with whenever I try to create a new document. I'll click "Create" and then "Document" and it won't be registered. I really need these issues fixed pronto, as I have to use this software every day. Please help!!

Comment: Maybe it's a caching issue. Try Ctrl+F5 or Ctrl+Shift+R.

Answer (score 2):

Just because a document was shared with you does not necessarily mean that you can edit it:   sometimes shared users only have viewing rights.

Fristly, the person who shared it should check in their settings what rights you have.